# Preventing windows to Ctrl+Alt+Del at logon

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to prevent windows to show the Ctrl+Alt+Del menu at logon, for that, I have to flip a registry value from 0 to 1, I developed this piece of code:

```
const string subkey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon";

RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(subkey, true);
myKey.SetValue("DisableCad", "1", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
myKey.Close();
```

But when I restart windows the Crtl+Alt+Del menus still shows up. Anyone knows whats the problem?

Comment: Crystal ball says that you run this code on a 64-bit version of Windows but you did not remove the jitter forcing.  So the value you write ends up in the Wow6432Node subkey.  Do use Regedit.exe to verify.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  And write 1, not "1".

Comment: Yes, that was it! Post it as an answer please so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Looks to me you've got everything to complete this Q+A by yourself.  Just write your own post and mark it as the answer to close your question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Hans Passant I found the answer.

The problem was that I was running this code for a 64-bit computer when I was compiling it for 32-bit...

To change this I just had to got to Project > Properties > Build tab, and uncheck the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.

Thank you Hans.